# Local binding of "self" to another variable in instance methods acceptable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Is it acceptable according to the standards of best practice to locally bind *self* in a instance method to another variable? It comes in handy, especially when testing the method. I would also like to like know whether this approach is more efficient if instance attributes are retrieve within loops. Here is an example

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "some attribute"

    def some_function(self):
        c = self
        for _ in range(10):
            print(c.a)
```

Comment: I don't think it's harmful or anything, but why would you want to do it? Why not just do `print(self.a)` inside your loop? Can you go into greater detail regarding "it comes in handy"?

Comment: Why would this come in handy when testing? It is not as if you can reach into that function to test what locals are bound to, so `self` vs. `c` doesn't make one jot of difference here. You can name that first argument anything you want, it doesn't have to be named `self`, anyway.

Comment: Some person seeing `c.a` when reading your code might easily miss out that `c` is just reference to the instance. `Explicit is better than implicit.`

Comment: Thank's for the comments. I actually didn't know that the first argument to a instance method does not need to have the name "self".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This generally offers no benefits, it is actually counter-intuitive in that it confuses readers as to what your intentions are (`self` is arguably the most recognizable name in Python).

The only up-side of doing this (albeit, a bit differently) is if you want to eliminate the attribute look-up on `self` by assigning the attribute to a name ([noted as a performance tip in the Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Avoiding_dots...)):

```
def some_function(self):
    # we assign 'self.a' to 'a'
    # to avoid looking for 'a' in 'self' for every iteration 
    a = self.a            
    for _ in range(10):
        print(a)
```

which will only help a bit by reducing execution speed on a minuscule degree. Other than that you really get no benefit of renaming `self` like that.

Comment: Recently I had some code where I had to call a function `self.data_grabber.buffer_cleave_left` about six times in the next few lines so I just renamed it: `n = self.data_grabber.buffer_cleave_left`.

Comment: @DJX  Eliminating `6 * 3` look-ups generally won't make *much* of a difference. In your case the upside is that you might make code more readable if you replace a long name with a shorter one.

Comment: You do have to be aware of what `a` is, though; if `self.a` is a property with side effects (probably a bad idea, but possible), looking it up once may be very different than looking it up 10 times.

Comment: @chepner of course, this is really a silly 'optimization', for many reasons. Python has speed issues that cannot be remedied by simply eliminating the dot. If someone is looking for optimization in Python he should look at the dozens of tools created to address that issue.